# send request in selenium without clicking on the send button in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have python script that use selenium to login website, you should insert the username and password and captcha for submit button to login.after this login webpage have send button  for send form information with post request, how can i bypass this clicking in button and  send the post request without  clicking on the button ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to try and bypass the captcha and go straight to the send button, I doubt that's possible. If you need to solve recaptchas, check out 2captcha.com and use their API to solve it - which will unlock the send button, theoretically.